# Set cursor of the textbox in the end

Tags: angular, html, typescript, textbox, chat

I need to create a user input form for chat messaging. 
For this reason, I use this HTML-code:

[HTML-code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32GtH.jpg)

When the user presses ENTER I get the text from textbox and save it,
When the user presses CTRL + ENTER I add '\n' to move message on the next line.

[TypeScript-code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UYl7.jpg)

But when I press the CTRL + ENTER the cursor moves to the beginning of input field.

How I can move it on the end? Thank you.

[Cursor result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5cZK.jpg)

Comment: Why ctrl + Enter, it shoud be Shift + ENTER, right?

Comment: There is no difference, in this case, CTRL + ENTER.

Answer (score 0):

Call the below function `setEndOfContenteditable($('.text-field'))`

Current given code is in Javascript Please convert to TypeScript

```
function setEndOfContenteditable(contentEditableElement) {
             var range,selection;
             if(document.createRange) { //Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, IE 9+
                range = document.createRange();//Create a range (a range is a like the selection but invisible)
                range.selectNodeContents(contentEditableElement);//Select the entire contents of the element with the range
                range.collapse(false);//collapse the range to the end point. false means collapse to end rather than the start
                selection = window.getSelection();//get the selection object (allows you to change selection)
                selection.removeAllRanges();//remove any selections already made
                selection.addRange(range);//make the range you have just created the visible selection
              }
              else if(document.selection)//IE 8 and lower
              { 
                 range = document.body.createTextRange();//Create a range (a range is a like the selection but invisible)
                 range.moveToElementText(contentEditableElement);//Select the entire contents of the element with the range
                 range.collapse(false);//collapse the range to the end point. false means collapse to end rather than the start
                 range.select();//Select the range (make it the visible selection
            }
         }
```